# Problem with InverseTransformDirection and non-uniform scale

Tags: unity, mathematics

I made the plane to work with mesh vertices

```
var plane = new Plane(
    hit.transform.InverseTransformDirection(normal),
    hit.transform.InverseTransformPoint(position)
);
```

If the object has the uniform scale then all looks good

[image: uniform is good]

but otherwise the plane normal has weird angle and I don't understand why.

[image: non-uniform has problems]

with InverseTransformVector even worser. The angle goes 2 times bigger

[image: worser]

Blue line - my plane
Green spheres - plane intersections
white sphere - plane center

Maybe it can be calculated directly with worldToLocalMatrix?

**UPDATE:**

Okay It is so weird for me. After InverseTransform plane prints in console right normal but has wrong real angle.

There is code to reproduce

Place component to default cube in zero position, rotate it with Y != 0, scale ONE horizontal dimesion. You will see onesided plane.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlaceOnCube : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 PlaneOrigin = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    public Vector3 PlaneNormal = new Vector3(1, 0, 0);

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.DrawSphere(PlaneOrigin, .03f);

        var plane = new Plane(
               transform.InverseTransformDirection(PlaneNormal),
               transform.InverseTransformPoint(PlaneOrigin)
               );

        ReGeneratePlane(plane);
    }

    private void ReGeneratePlane(Plane plane)
    {
        var meshfilter = transform.GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
        var mesh = meshfilter.mesh;
        var tris = mesh.triangles;
        var verts = mesh.vertices;
        var newTris = new int[36 + 6];
        var newVerts = new Vector3[24 + 4];

        for (int j = 0; j < verts.Length; j++)
            newVerts[j] = verts[j];

        newVerts[24] = plane.ClosestPointOnPlane(new Vector3(-2, -1, 0));
        newVerts[25] = plane.ClosestPointOnPlane(new Vector3(2, -1, 0));
        newVerts[26] = plane.ClosestPointOnPlane(new Vector3(-2, 1, 0));
        newVerts[27] = plane.ClosestPointOnPlane(new Vector3(2, 1, 0));

        for (int j = 0; j < tris.Length; j++)
            newTris[j] = tris[j];

        newTris[36] = 24;
        newTris[37] = 26;
        newTris[38] = 25;
        newTris[39] = 26;
        newTris[40] = 27;
        newTris[41] = 25;

        mesh.vertices = newVerts;
        mesh.triangles = newTris;

        meshfilter.mesh = mesh;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to use InverseTransformVector if you wanted scale to be included?

Comment: @DMGregory I updated question. InverseTransformVector dont work

Comment: Sounds like you should show us your code for placing these points so we can help you debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good person suggested the correct answer on another resource

To fix the scaling, instead of

```
transform.InverseTransformDirection(PlaneNormal)
```

should use

```
 transform.localToWorldMatrix.transpose.MultiplyVector(PlaneNormal)
```